# Efficiently find indexes that would make array equal to a permutation of itself

Tags: numpy, permutation

I'm looking for some function that find the indexes that would make an array equal to a permutation of itself.

Assume that `p1` is a 1d Numpy array that contains no duplicates. Assume that `p2` is a permutation (a reordering) of `p1`.

I want a function `find_position_in_original` such that `p2[find_position_in_original(p2, p1)]` is identical to `p1`.

For example:

```
p1 = np.array(['a', 'e', 'c', 'f'])
p2 = np.array(['e', 'f', 'a', 'c'])
```

in which `find_position_in_permutation(p1, p2)` should return:

```
[2, 0, 1, 3]
```

because `p2[[2, 0, 1, 3]]` is identical to `p1`.

You can do this in a brute-force manner using lists:

```
def find_position_in_permutation(original, permutation):
    original = list(original)
    permutation = list(permutation)
    return list(map(permutation.index, original))
```

but I am wondering if there is something more algorithmically efficient. This one appears to be `O(N^2)`.

---

Benchmarks of current answers:

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

n = 100

letters = np.array([*ascii_lowercase])
p1 = np.random.choice(letters, size=n)
p2 = np.random.permutation(p1)
p1l = p1.tolist()
p2l = p2.tolist()

def find_pos_in_perm_1(original, permutation):
    """ My original solution """
    return list(map(permutation.index, original))

def find_pos_in_perm_2(original, permutation):
    """ Eric Postpischil's solution, using a dict as a lookup table """
    tbl = {val: ix for ix, val in enumerate(permutation)}
    return [tbl[val] for val in original]

def find_pos_in_perm_3(original, permutation):
    """ Paul Panzer's solution, using an array as a lookup table """
    original_argsort = np.argsort(original)
    permutation_argsort = np.argsort(permutation)
    tbl = np.empty_like(original_argsort)
    tbl[original_argsort] = permutation_argsort
    return tbl

%timeit find_pos_in_perm_1(p1l, p2l)
# 40.5 µs ± 1.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit find_pos_in_perm_2(p1l, p2l)
# 10 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit find_pos_in_perm_3(p1, p2)
# 6.38 µs ± 157 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Sounds like a search problem.  That's not a numpy strength.

Comment: I am not familiar with numpy. I presume these arrays are usable with regular Python functions, not just through numpy. If so, an O(n log n) solution is to insert an ordered pair (value, index) into a balanced tree for each element in one array, then look up each element of the other array in the tree. Python’s dictionary type may serve that purpose, although I do not know what its underlying implementation is. (Could be a tree, could be a hash table, could be something else—may serve your performance need whatever it is.)

Comment: If Python does not provide built-in types suitable for this, another solution is to map each array to a list of (value, index), and then sort each lists. The indices in the two sorted then represent the permutation that sorted them. Composing one permutation with the inverse of the other will provide the permutation you seek. That is two O(n log n) sorts and one O(n) composition, so it is O(n log n).

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, they can be converted to regular lists as in my brute-force implementation. Your first solution should work with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do O(N log N) using argsort:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> 
>>> letters = np.array([*ascii_lowercase])
>>> p1, p2 = map(np.random.permutation, 2*(letters,))
>>> 
>>> o1, o2 = map(np.argsort, (p1, p2))
>>> o12, o21 = map(np.empty_like, (o1, o2))
>>> o12[o1], o21[o2] = o2, o1
>>> 
>>> print(np.all(p1[o21] == p2))
True
>>> print(np.all(p2[o12] == p1))
True
```

O(N) solution using Python dictionary:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>>    
>>> l1, l2 = map(op.methodcaller('tolist'), (p1, p2))
>>> 
>>> s12 = op.itemgetter(*l1)({k: v for v, k in enumerate(l2)})
>>> print(np.all(s12 == o12))
True
```

Some timings:

```
26 elements
argsort      0.004 ms
dict         0.003 ms
676 elements
argsort      0.096 ms
dict         0.075 ms
17576 elements
argsort      4.366 ms
dict         2.915 ms
456976 elements
argsort    191.376 ms
dict       230.459 ms
```

Benchmark code:

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase
import operator as op
from timeit import timeit

L1 = np.array([*ascii_lowercase], object)
L2 = np.add.outer(L1, L1).ravel()
L3 = np.add.outer(L2, L1).ravel()
L4 = np.add.outer(L2, L2).ravel()
letters = (*map(op.methodcaller('astype', str), (L1, L2, L3, L4)),)

def use_argsort(p1, p2):
    o1, o2 = map(np.argsort, (p1, p2))
    o12 = np.empty_like(o1)
    o12[o1] = o2
    return o12

def use_dict(l1, l2):
    return op.itemgetter(*l1)({k: v for v, k in enumerate(l2)})

for L, N in zip(letters, (1000, 1000, 200, 4)):
    print(f'{len(L)} elements')
    p1, p2 = map(np.random.permutation, (L, L))
    l1, l2 = map(op.methodcaller('tolist'), (p1, p2))
    T = (timeit(lambda: f(i1, i2), number=N)*1000/N for f, i1, i2 in (
        (use_argsort, p1, p2), (use_dict, l1, l2)))
    for m, t in zip(('argsort', 'dict   '), T):
        print(m, f'{t:10.3f} ms')
```

Comment: On small lists, this turns out to be faster than both my original solution and the proposal by Eric Postpischil.

Comment: @shadowtalker Added my own benchmarks. `dict` approach looks quite competitive. Note that using `operator.itemgetter` for bulk dictionary lookup seems to give a massive speedup over list comprehension.